# Vue JS - Update data value while processing zip file

Tags: vue.js, fs, adm-zip

I think I am missing something with Vue JS reactivity here.

My problem is that some data values are not updating while I am unzipping a file using File System and Adm-Zip.

Here is some pseudo code to show my issue.

```js
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            unzipped: 0,
            total: 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        unzipFile (fileName) {
            var that = this

            let r = fs.createReadStream(fileName)
            let w = fs.createWriteStream('archive.zip')

            let i = 0

            r.pipe(w).on('close', function () {

                    var zip = new AdmZip('archive.zip')
                    var zipEntries = zip.getEntries()

                    that.total = zipEntries.length // not updating

                    zipEntries.forEach(function (zipEntry) {
                        zip.extractEntryTo(zipEntry.entryName, dir + 'video', false, true)
                        i++
                        that.unzipped = i // not updating
                    })

            })
            // updates are made here
        }
    }
}
```

`that.total` and `that.unzipped` are not updating while the code executes.

Here is the template code where I show the progress.

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ unzipped }}/{{ total }}
    </div>
</template>
```

Any help appreciated.

**Edit**
Here is a tested method where the data properties are updated successfully.

```
testUpdate () {
    var that = this
    that.total = 100
    setInterval(() => {
        that.unzipped++
    }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: How do you know they're not updating? Are you even calling `unzipFile()`?

Comment: Is your issue reproducible without streams? For example, can you reproduce the issue with timeouts? It may have nothing to do with the streams.

Comment: @Phil, yes, I am calling the method. As I mentioned, this is pseudo code, I only included relevant parts

Comment: Could you please address my first question... _"How do you know they're not updating?"_

Comment: @DylanLandry, yes, just updated my question with a setInterval test and it works there

Comment: Also, what library is providing `fs` in the browser?

Comment: Sorry @Phil, because in my template I have `{{ unzipped }}/{{ total }}` and it does not update.

Comment: @Phil, `fs` is nodejs filesystem (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Comment: Yes, but your Vue code runs in the browser. Have you checked your console for errors? I suspect there might be some

Comment: @Phil, no errors, console.log works in the extract routine but data properties do not update

Comment: Is the close event firing? Like Phil suggests, maybe that method throws because fd module doesn't exist. Maybe try adding an new reactive property to a data object with `vue.set`, to see if that works.

Comment: `Vue.set` does not work either. It appears that the whole view freezes during the unzip process. Perhaps I need to step out the extraction of each file into a method and wait until it is finished before the next. Thanks for all the help.